# how can calculate precisely the diagonal movement?

Tags: javascript

Sorry for the duplicate questions, but i still stuck with problems many days.Its caused by the function calculate for the diagonal movement.I have already search and try but it just work for a few tile and after that my character being go in other ways.I have search in same problem and may be its cause by the coordinate, that have to normalize the vector, but im not sure is it true or not my problem here?

```
if (obj[i].direction == "topleft") {
                    this.player_x -= Math.sin(rad) / 16 ;  
                    this.player_y -= Math.cos(rad) / 16 ;  
                    this.player_walking = 1;
                    this.player_direction = 0;

                } else if (obj[i].direction == "bottomleft") {  
                    this.player_x += Math.sin(rad) / 16 ;  
                    this.player_y -= Math.cos(rad) / 16 ;  
                    this.player_walking = 1;
                    this.player_direction = 2;

                } else if (obj[i].direction == "topright") {
                    this.player_x += Math.sin(rad) / 16 ;  
                    this.player_y -= Math.cos(rad) / 16 ;  
                    this.player_walking = 1;
                    this.player_direction = 1;

                }else if (obj[i].direction == "bottomright") {
                    this.player_x += Math.sin(rad) / 16 ;  
                    this.player_y += Math.cos(rad) / 16 ;  
                    this.player_walking = 1;
                    this.player_direction = 3;
}
```

This my statement where calculate the direction diagonal.I very admire for any helping and Thank all for help me

This is my codepen [link](https://codepen.io/chew-chew23/pen/WNKNRNj?editors=1111)

Comment: I tried the pen and I don't understand about the diagonal you stated in the question? Do you want the character able to move diagonally? Or could you please elaborate more?

Comment: yes i want it move diagonal in the exactly coordinate of tiles that create by a star algorithms,from all i know is i have to plus/negative the [x y] with the radian

Comment: You want the movement like if you are currently on tile (0,0), then you can move to tile (1,1) by only one move, not two, right? And what key do you expect to make the character move diagonally? Combined arrow keypresses?

Comment: In the second and third case you modify the coordinates in the same way. The second case is wrong: it should have `-=` for the x-coordinate, since it is a *left* move, and it should have a `+=` for the y-coordinate since it is a *downward* move.

Comment: @Dhana D yes it exactly i want the movement the first button is create path and the second button named 'GO' is starting movement of character

Comment: @trincot sorry for that because of that but i belive even though i fix the negative or plus it still be like that problem

Comment: I see some trigonometry problems there.. the sin rules the y and cos should rule the x. The `/16` is tricky... technically it's a matter of multiplying by a radius that should be the distance between the starting point and the destination. The `rad` should be a value between `0-2Pi` in the full circle

Comment: so i tried yet , i replace the angle is  const rad = angle * (Math.PI / 360) ;360 not 180 and make y is sin and x is cos but still getting that problem

Comment: @chew, please edit your question. It should be reproducible for us. Linking to a code base with 1800+ lines is not helpful. And clearly something is wrong (see  my previous comment), so please correct that in your question as well. I suggest you make a new sample program without all the graphics, which **only** prints some coordinates and which demonstrates the issue. It should need no more than 100 lines of code. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: PS: the integers for `this.player_direction` make no sense. What do they represent? Why do you use the same integers, the same as for the `up, left, down, right` directions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't use a [joystick controller](https://github.com/rokobuljan/gamepad) (which returns a wider range of angle values) but only **keyboard arrow keys** to move your character **diagonally**, you don't need anything special but

```js
// If single arrow key:
distance = 1

// If combo arrow keys:
distance = 1 / Math.sqrt(2)     // ~0.707
```

which will give you the needed diagonal movement distance of `~0.707`
and once you've defined your distance value, multiply it by the speed:

```js
distance *= speed;
```

the rest is then pretty straightforward:

```js
if (K[37]) Player.x -= distance;
if (K[38]) Player.y -= distance;
if (K[39]) Player.x += distance;
if (K[40]) Player.y += distance;
```

[image]

**Demo example**:

```js
const Player = {
  el: document.getElementById('player'),
  x: 200,
  y: 100,
  speed: 2,
  move() {
    // You will use canvas, this is for demo only
    this.el.style.transform = `translate(${this.x}px, ${this.y}px)`;
  }
};

const K = {
  fn(ev) {
    const k = ev.which;
    if (k >= 37 && k <= 40) {  // If is arrow
      ev.preventDefault();
      K[k] = ev.type === "keydown";
    }
  }
};

const update = () => {
  let dist = K[38] && (K[37] || K[39]) || K[40] && (K[37] || K[39]) ? 0.707 : 1;
  dist *= Player.speed;
  if (K[37]) Player.x -= dist;
  if (K[38]) Player.y -= dist;
  if (K[39]) Player.x += dist;
  if (K[40]) Player.y += dist;
  Player.move();
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', K.fn);
document.addEventListener('keyup', K.fn);

(function engine() {
  update();
  requestAnimationFrame(engine);
}());
```

```css
#player{ position: absolute; left: 0;  top: 0; width: 20px;  height: 20px; background: #000;  border-radius: 50%; }
```

```html
Click here to focus, and use arrows
<div id="player"></div>
```

Comment: oh thank you so much , i did it and it became right the way, i put like you say and divide to 16 and it work, i am none of word to say and express for but thank so much again a

Comment: @chew you're very welcome! Glad you made it work

Answer (score 0):

As I explained in my comment, there were some problems on how did you use trigonometry to determine the x and y offset based on the angle and the distance.

You did this:

```
this.player_x += Math.sin(rad) / 16 ;  
this.player_y -= Math.cos(rad) / 16 ;
```

But it didn't make sense because sin and cos are respectively the y and x.

Anyway I made a very small demo that will show the concept having a small box that can be moved on ***TL***, ***TR***, ***BL*** and ***BR*** directions of a `radius` amount defined as constant.

I later refactored your code so that it's pointless to have an if for each direction since you always just need to add the sin and cos values to the coordinates. The angles come from an object mapping each direction to the corresponding angle and the radius instead of being predefined, it comes from the value of the `distance` input and can be set at any time before performing the movement.

Since to make it more clear I also map those coords to the position of a dom element, I had to transform the y coord doing `* -1` in accordance with how the `top` css property works (from top to bottom).

The angles are predetermined for each direction as a fraction of PI.

There are better ways to make it more efficient but it's just for the sake of showing the concept:

```js
//const radius = 30;

const p1 = new player('#p1');

function player(target){
  
  const pi_tr = Math.PI*(1/4); //45deg
  const pi_tl = Math.PI*(3/4); //135deg
  const pi_bl = Math.PI*(5/4); //225deg
  const pi_br = Math.PI*(7/4); //315deg
  
  this.target = document.querySelector(target);
  this.player_x = 0;
  this.player_y = 0;      

  this.logCoords = ()=>{
    console.log(`X: ${this.player_x}, Y: ${this.player_y}`);
  }

  this.showPosition = ()=>{
    this.target.style.left = `${this.player_x}px`;
    this.target.style.top =  `${this.player_y*-1}px`;
  }

  this.move = (direction)=>{

    const anglesByDirection = {
      'topleft': {
        rad: pi_tl,        
        directionCode: 0
      },
      'bottomleft': {
        rad: pi_bl,        
        directionCode: 2        
      },
      'topright': {
        rad: pi_tr,
        directionCode: 1        
      },
      'bottomright': {
        rad: pi_br,        
        directionCode: 3        
      }
    }
    
    const radius = parseInt( document.getElementById('distance').value );
    const angle = anglesByDirection[direction];
    
    this.player_x += Math.cos(angle.rad) * radius;
    this.player_y += Math.sin(angle.rad) * radius;
    
    this.player_walking = 1;
    this.player_direction = angle.directionCode;
    
    this.logCoords();
    this.showPosition();  
  }


}
```

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.controls{
  border: solid 1px lightgray;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.controls button{
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.controls .distance{
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.controls #distance{ 
  width: 2em;
}

.controls #distance+span{
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#game{
  position: relative;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  border: dashed 2px gray;
}

#p1{
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="controls">
  <button class="TL" onclick="p1.move('topleft');">TL</button>
  <button class="TR" onclick="p1.move('topright');">TR</button>
  <br>
  <button class="BL" onclick="p1.move('bottomleft');">BL</button>
  <button class="BR" onclick="p1.move('bottomright');">BR</button>
  <br>
  <div class="distance">
    <label for="distance">Distance</label>
    <input type="text" id="distance" data-default="30" value="30"><span>px</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="game">
  <div id="p1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry for the messed code because i just starting with it a few day, but seem like if i multiple with angle like you say it is worse more than.I just thought it will have divided to x and y and make them with the angle minimize more because i set every tile just 16px 16px so that why every my character going just about 0.5

Comment: it's just a matter of understanding the conditions. The demo shows what's the point on using sin and cos to move the x and y values while having the point moving a given amount. It's just a pitagorean approach to the problem using trigonometry. The way you were using it was pretty hard to understand and wrong in terms of math. There's the chance that since you are using tiles you should "quantize" the function domains. Anyway I didn't get a word of what you meant in your comment. But again I want to stress you were using the math wrong. Not the code.. the math